How many times can a question be added to a reopen queue via editing?
There is a question on this site that was poorly received and closed 10 days ago. Since then, it was trivially edited a number of times, with the result that it has been added to the reopen queue 19 times and counting.
Is there a limit to the number of attempts a user has to 'resolve the original reasons for closure' (as pictured below) ?

If as this MSE QA suggests there is not a software limit, is there a community-defined limit? This need not be a hard-and-fast or precise number.
Finally, if there is not a community consensus: should there be one?


Notes: I haven't linked the particular question but I am happy to if it would help- I wanted to avoid 'naming and shaming'; though the user does have an interesting history on the network and elsewhere. And by 'trivial', I mean edits that tweak phrasing, add fluff, etc while not altering the substance of the question. I am happy to edit both of these aspects into my question if those would be of benefit. Cheers!

If we feel a policy is necessary, I would recommend following similar guidelines we established when dealing with individuals making large numbers of gratuitous tag edits.  I propose that if a user makes 4 consecutive edits within a weeks time, resubmitting the question for review each time, and the reviewers judge that the original close reasons were not dealt with on each of these consecutive edits, that the question be locked for a week. Second offense begin the suspension cycle with the user for low quality contributions or rule violations if we accept this as policy.

I think your suggestion makes sense and is reasonable, I'll leave the Q without an accepted answer for a little while longer for others who would like to suggest a policy :)

I don't know that there's a hard limit in the software.
If it has approached the point where its just harassing reviewers rather than a legitimate attempt to improve the question and the site, I'd say flag it. Site mods can perform actions like lock changes on the question for a while to deter spamming, and/or talk to the culprit (optionally including suspension).
Excessive edits to a post do get automatically flagged. However, that usually happens because someone is trying to incrementally improve a post they wrote (fix spelling and grammar errors, respond to comments, fix errors in the new content that responds to comments, etc.) So it wouldn't be weird for a moderator to miss that there's malicious intent behind it this time.

Thanks for the answer, this is a useful view with actionable advice, viz: "If it has approached the point where its [not] a legitimate attempt to improve the question and the site, I'd say flag it."

While I have accepted the other answer because it proposes a policy and a reasonable threshold for action, the advice "flag it" is worth re-emphasising :)
